# How to use jfreechart in unix

Tags: java, jfreechart

I had a java program which uses jfreechart API to create histogram, which is running fine in windows system but the same is not running in unix system. It is saying NoClassDef exception. I have added the jfreechart jar to the lib in Unix... Do I need to do anything else to make it run?

Comment: NO... Nothing more...

Comment: @codeMaker: `jcommon` is required, too.

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDef exceptions are really only thrown for the fact the class simply doesn't exist.

Are you running the application through an IDE?  If so, make sure the jar is in the classpath.  If not, make sure you're including it in the command prompt.

```
java -classpath thirdpartyjar.jar mainclass.java
```

There can be no reason for this exception other than the class doesn't exist or the lib is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that both the `jfreechart` and `jcommon` JARs are on the `classpath`, along with your class.

In this example, the required libraries are cited in the `Class-Path` attribute of the JAR's  manifest:

> $ java -cp jfreechart-1.0.14-demo.jar demo.BarChartDemo1

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513), `DTSCTest.class` is in `build/classes`, the the libraries are in `dist/lib`:

> $ java -cp build/classes:dist/lib/* chart.DTSCTest

See [`java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) for details.